# C# Windows Adding SE_BACKUP_NAME

Tags: windows, backup, elevated-privileges

I have an app that runs as LOCALSYSTEM (full rights). I need to add SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME privileges to the app. How do I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: You probably have them, you just need to enable them.

Comment: Not exactly sure how